# Error de compilación. Memory Reading & Writing C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema de compilación, es tan solo una advertencia que se convierte en un error. Puedo hacer un bypass de esto con un simple #pragma warning(disable: %%%)

Pero quiero saber cual es el problema exacto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    #include <ntdef.h>
#include <ntifs.h>



DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
#pragma alloc_text(INIT, DriverEntry)
#pragma warning(disable: 4100)

NTSTATUS NTAPI MmCopyVirtualMemory
(
    PEPROCESS SourceProcess,
    PVOID SourceAddress,
    PEPROCESS TargetProcess,
    PVOID TargetAddress,
    SIZE_T BufferSize,
    KPROCESSOR_MODE PreviousMode,
    PSIZE_T ReturnSize
);

NTKERNELAPI
NTSTATUS
PsLookupProcessByProcessId(
    _In_ HANDLE ProcessId,
    _Outptr_ PEPROCESS *Process
);

NTSTATUS KeReadProcessMemory(PEPROCESS Process, PVOID SourceAddress, PVOID TargetAddress, SIZE_T Size)
{
    PEPROCESS SourceProcess = Process;
    PEPROCESS TargetProcess = PsGetCurrentProcess();
    SIZE_T Result;
    if (NT_SUCCESS(MmCopyVirtualMemory(SourceProcess, SourceAddress, TargetProcess, TargetAddress, Size, KernelMode, &Result)))
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    else
        return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
}
NTSTATUS KeWriteProcessMemory(PEPROCESS Process, PVOID SourceAddress, PVOID TargetAddress, SIZE_T Size)
{      
    PEPROCESS SourceProcess = PsGetCurrentProcess();
    PEPROCESS TargetProcess = Process;
    SIZE_T Result;

    if (NT_SUCCESS(MmCopyVirtualMemory(SourceProcess, SourceAddress, TargetProcess, TargetAddress, Size, KernelMode, &Result)))
        return STATUS_SUCCESS; 
    else
        return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;

}


NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
    _In_  struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject,
    _In_  PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
)
{
    int Writeval = 6969;

    PEPROCESS Process; 
    PsLookupProcessByProcessId(6556, &Process);

    KeWriteProcessMemory(Process, &Writeval, 0x0022B000, sizeof(__int32));

    DbgPrint("Changed to: %d", Writeval);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Es muy difícil saber qué está provocando este error si no nos muestras el código sospechoso de provocarlo...

Comment: Hola @Lucas , bienvenido a stackoverflow. Por favor, para poder ayudarte necesitamos que nos prepares un [MCVE (ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable)](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Si no conocemos cómo es la declaración de tus variables, cómo las pasas a la función, etc no podremos saber qué estás haciendo mal, nuestras dotes adivinatorias son limitadas. Y, por favor, que no sean imágenes. Gracias.

Comment: Bueno, viendo que tu aplicación te está diciendo dónde está el fallo... [mira la documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551920(v=vs.85).aspx): `(HANDLE)4872` y te podrás imaginar el siguiente.

Comment: @OscarGarcia , ahi esta :)

Comment: Gracias por compartir el código. Te respondí de manera más amplia con los dos errores de conversión de tipos. Si lo haces así debería solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu editor está diciendo dónde está el fallo en la zona subrayada.

[Mira la documentación de `PsLookupProcessByProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551920(v=vs.85).aspx): el primer parámetro es de tipo `HANDLE`.

```
PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)4872, &Process);
```

Y luego tienes [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) y tu definición `KeReadProcessMemory(PEPROCESS Process, PVOID SourceAddress, PVOID TargetAddress, SIZE_T Size)`:

```
KeWriteProcessMemory(Process, &Writeval, (LPCVOID)0x0022B000, sizeof(__int32));
```

Tu función necesita ese tipo de dato, por lo que debes indicar explícitamente la conversión de datos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias lo he solucionado!

Comment: De nada, un placer :)